# Hyper-V 2012 R2 and File shares

Tags: iscsi, file-sharing, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I currently have a 2008 R2 hyper-v cluster but I am going to be building a new 2012 R2 failover hyper-v 2012 r2 cluster in the next few weeks and wanted to get some opinions on running a large file share within a hyper-v guest.

Currently, we have two domain controllers; one virtual, one bare metal. The bare metal is hosting our file share on local disk, which we've almost consumed completely. I have two large Winsys SAN devices (one fibre channel and one iSCSI) at my disposal that have tons of storage for the foreseeable future and I plan on using one of them as a CSV.

I was thinking (when the cluster is complete) I would build a new vm guest that would be promoted to a DC (that would eventually replace the old bare metal DC) and add a second virtual drive to the guest DC with around 6 TB of storage.

Will server 2012 R2 handle a 6 TB vhdx over iSCSI or FC ok? Or should I consider a different approach?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have 6TB of data on the current DC?

Comment: I do not. We have just under 2 TB. However, I was considering combining other data sources with it, which would bump it up to about 3 TB or so. I wanted to create a 6 TB source so that it would last the next 3 years or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will handle that just fine.

But I would recommend separating it from the DC.  Setup one VM as just a domain controller and another as the fileserver.

It might also make sense, depending on your usage, to split the shares across multiple VHDXs, simple because large ones are more time consuming to move around and cant easily be split between storage devices or different speeds of physical disks.